# DDl compare validator

Tags: asp.net

I had ddl and I added compare validator to make user choose from DDl.And I set all it,s properties well but when i forget to select ddl the validator apear well but when I selected from ddl The astrics(*) as error text it was still apear although I added it,s property focus on error=true.So please any one help me.

*

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try to use another validator. It sounds like using the CustomValidator instead of the CompareValidator would be your way to go.

The asterix means that one of your validators says that your page is not valid. Try to set a breakpoint and determine which validator is not valid.